# How can I show reduction from every language in RE to HP

Tags: turing-machines, computation

L is considered to be Hard-RE if for every L' in RE, there is a reduction from L' to L (L'<=L)
L is considered to be Complete-RE if L id Hard-RE and also L is in RE.

How can I prove that HP is complete-RE? i will need to show reduction from every language in RE to HP..

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming RE means [recursively enumerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) and HP means the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))

## HP is trivially in RE

Consider the Turing machine that, given the description *a* of a Turing machine *M[a]* and some input *b*, just simulates running *M[a]* wiht input *b* until it halts; and when it does, it outputs *TRUE*. This machine will output *TRUE* iff *M[a]* halts for *b*, and will diverge when *M[a]* diverges; so it is a partial decider for the halting problem.

## HP is RE-Hard

That is, given a language L in RE, it is reducable to HP: since L is in RE, there exists a Turing machine *M[m(L)]* such that for any input *b*, *M[m(L)](b)* will do one of the following:

1. If *b*∈L, then *M[m(L)](b)* halts with output *TRUE*
2. *b*∉L and *M[m(L)](b)* halts with output *FALSE*
3. *b*∉L and *M[m(L)](b)* diverges

So how do we turn that into a proper decider for L, given HP? Easy peasy! Just run your HP oracle on *(m(L), b)*!

- If *HP(m(L), b)* returns *TRUE*, we know that *M[m(L)](b)* converges, so just run it and return whatever *TRUE*/*FALSE* answer it results in.
- If *HP(m(L), b)* return s_FALSE_, we know that *M[m(L)](b)* diverges, which it is only allowed to do if *b*∉L (see case 3 above). So we then **don't** run *M[m(L)](b)*; instead, we just output *FALSE*.

## Thus, HP is RE-Complete

Q.E.D.

Comment: I had a lot of fun reconstructing this proof from just the definitions of RE and reducability.